# How to get acknowledgement of a successful print event

Tags: php, printing

**Can we know whether the user's printer device has successfully printed the required document?**

We have a web-based application developed using LAMP (Linux, Apache, Mysql and PHP). We provide user with a button on each report which prints the report.

Some of the reports require to be tagged as "duplicate" if it has been printed earlier. We used to set the flag if user clicks on "Print". The problem occurred when in some cases, the user clicked the "Print" button and, unfortunately, their printer got jammed.

With my best knowledge, it is possible if the printer sends an ACK after printing the document successfully.

Pardon me for grammatical errors or the way of putting-up the question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the browser does not have access to this level of detail of the printing process, and therefore neither does PHP. PHP produces HTML output which it sends to the browser; the browser can print this document, but there's no detailed Javascript API for the page to interact with this printing process, so your code will not get any feedback. Further, once the browser has produced a print job it usually goes off into a system wide print spool, where it may wait a while, or may get distributed to other spools or what not. In other words, this is all several layers of abstractions removed.

You'd need a client-side application which can hook deeply into the print spool infrastructure in order to monitor specific print jobs and receive feedback on it. A regular website won't do. At the very least something along the lines of an ActiveX or Java browser plugin.

Comment: Dear Deceze,

Thanks a lot!

I will stick to develop a client-side application as suggested and will post here if successful.